# Quaternions group $\{\pm 1 , \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ is not isomorphism to Diedral Group $D_4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions

How to prove that quaternions group $G=\{\pm 1 , \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ is not isomorphism to Diedral Group $D_4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the elements of both groups. For example in $Q_8$ we have only one element of order $2$ while $D_8$ has $5$ elements of order $2$.

Comment: Actually, the dihedral group has $5$ elements of order $2$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Sorry you are right!

Answer (score 0):

You could work out their respective Cayley graphs and notice they are different.